# No longer able to use Provider like I was able to in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

You cannot do this in flutter anymore

```
final classes = Provider.of<List<ClassData>>(context);
```

they force you to get the one that you created however many widgets ago.

for example here lets say when I start the app I do a provider call like this.

```
if (user == null) {
      return SignIn();
    } else {
      return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<List<ClassData>>.value(
              value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).classdata),
          StreamProvider<Tutor>.value(
            value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).streamTutor,
          )
        ],
        builder: (context, child) {
          if (user == null) {
            return SignIn();
          } else {
            Tutor tutor = Provider.of<Tutor>(context);

            if (tutor == null) {
              return RegisterTutor();
            } else {
           
              return Tutors();
            }
          }
        },
      );
    }
```

As you can see the List provider is right here. This is where it starts. If you do not pass in this data from here. You will not be able to access the data later. I have multiple points in my app where I do not pass in the provider directly into the widget so this is a huge problem. I just updated firebase and firestore and provider, and they seem to be making people do it "Their way".

As long as I pass in the data into each widget instead of later calling List classdata = Provider.of<List>(context) there is no errors. However if I do call the list like that in a later widget, one that is an ancestor of the multiprovider then it results in an error. can anyone tell me why this is or if there is a fix. I am going to have to re-write about 2,000 lines of code otherwise

Comment: I cannot see if there is an actual "fix" in place maybe it would be good to get in contact with the Firebase Support and ask for this specific scenario and maybe they should be aware since they are pushing for a change.

Comment: you have to wrap it in MaterialApp @StefanNeacsu